# Access to singleton instance fails with derived class

Tags: c#

I have a database wrapper code like this (pseudo code):

```
class MyDBWrapper<objecttype> : Singleton
{
    private DBDriver _Driver

    Driver => Instance._Driver; 

    ... tons of static functionality here referencing the driver
}
```

and then I can create custom databases from it:

```
class ObjectA_DB : MyDBWrapper<ObjectA_Type>
{
    ... all my calls using the static functionalities of the base class
}
```

this works very well...

Now, comes a different scenario:

I have a generic object: BaseObject
and a bunch of derived objects: ObjectA, ObjectB, etc

and they all require the same database code, so I did that:

```
class MyGenericDB<T> : MyDBWrapper<T> where T : BaseObject
{
    .. common functionality
}
```

and then instantiated the type specific classes like this:

```
class MyTypeA_DB : MyGenericDB<ObjectA_Type>
class MyTypeB_DB : MyGenericDB<ObjectB_Type>
```

and this compiles properly, however the singleton code is causing problem when I try to access the instance
as it seems like it's recursing. Visual studio is unable to give a proper error as to what happens, but it hangs then crashes, so I am guessing a stack overflow.

The singleton code is here:

```
public abstract class Singleton<T> where T : class
{
    private static readonly Lazy<T> _Instance = new Lazy<T>(CreateInstanceOfT, LazyThreadSafetyMode.PublicationOnly);
    protected static T Instance => _Instance.Value;
    private static T CreateInstanceOfT()
    {
        return Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), true) as T;
    }
}
```

Did I miss anything obvious?

Comment: Why not use [Lazy Initialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/performance/lazy-initialization)?

Comment: what do you mean? it has lazy initialization since the instance is created only when I first access it.

Comment: Sorry, I've overread that.

Comment: The class that you've called a "singleton" isn't actually a singleton.  You allow multiple instances to be created, making it not a singleton.

Comment: The goal of that class is to keep a single database driver, one per derived instance. Do you have a mechanic in mind that would work better?

Comment: Leaving aside that this doesn't implement the singleton pattern, why is singleton a base type in the first place? Normally you make a base type when the derived classes have something in common; "there's only one of me" seems like a strange thing to have in common. The singleton pattern code is very short and simple and you probably need it in less than half a dozen places; just duplicate it.

Comment: What I left out is that the base class is very large, it's all the CRUD DB operations with error handling, etc. So, in this model, each time a new type of object (= a new collection / table) is used, there is a class with that object deriving from the base class and it can use all the low level functionalities.

Comment: Everything in these classes is typically static but the DB driver because a bunch of logic needs to be executed before it's instantiated and it also gets a bunch of parameters from attributes, so the 'singleton' is really there to instantiate one DB driver per type of derived object. The system works very well, but now in my case, I want to add another layer of derived class, to re-use logic common to multiple collections/tables and this is where the system seems to fail

Answer (score 0):

Not that used to this version of generics as my main work is in unity, and they update their core every decade, but I am pretty sure that you need your instance to be public to be allowed to read it.

When I write this, I traditionally create a private static instance of the passed type, and follow that up with a public static access function that creates that type if it does not yet exist.

A good full example for my own main engine can be found here: 
http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Singleton.